# Framework not found FBLPromises Problem with Pods

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I really stuck with problem Framework not found FBLPromises Problem. I also noticed [image]

I try a lot of different solutions:

- Excluded architect arm64
- Build active architecture only
- Reinstalled Pods
- Deployment target everywhere is ios 14.0

My pod file

```
platform :ios, '14.0'
target 'Monopoly Money Counter' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' 
end
```

I am using M1 Mac. Really looking for a solution for a few days. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Here is a full error overview

```
Ld /Users/Serg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Monopoly_Money_Counter-dlchnwqjswrpalbdpoofeqhxekuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Monopoly\ Money\ Counter.app/Monopoly\ Money\ Counter normal (in target 'Monopoly Money Counter' from project 'Monopoly Money Counter')
    cd /Users/Serg/Documents/GitHub/iOS-Courses/iOS-Dev-2.0/Xcodes/MMC
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target x86_64-apple-ios15.2-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk -L/Users/Serg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Monopoly_Money_Counter-dlchnwqjswrpalbdpoofeqhxekuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Serg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Monopoly_Money_Counter-dlchnwqjswrpalbdpoofeqhxekuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/Serg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Monopoly_Money_Counter-dlchnwqjswrpalbdpoofeqhxekuc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Monopoly\ Money\ Counter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Monopoly\ Money\ Counter.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Monopoly\ Money\ Counter.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/Serg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Monopoly_Money_Counter-dlchnwqjswrpalbdpoofeqhxekuc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Monopoly\ Money\ Counter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Monopoly\ Money\ Counter.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Monopoly\ Money\ Counter_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/Serg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Monopoly_Money_Counter-dlchnwqjswrpalbdpoofeqhxekuc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Monopoly\ Money\ Counter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Monopoly\ Money\ Counter.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Monopoly_Money_Counter.swiftmodule -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreVideo -framework FBLPromises -framework GoogleAppMeasurement -framework GoogleAppMeasurementIdentitySupport -framework GoogleMobileAds -framework GoogleUtilities -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UserMessagingPlatform -framework WebKit -framework nanopb -weak_framework AdSupport -weak_framework JavaScriptCore -weak_framework SafariServices -weak_framework WebKit -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/Serg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Monopoly_Money_Counter-dlchnwqjswrpalbdpoofeqhxekuc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Monopoly\ Money\ Counter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Monopoly\ Money\ Counter.build/Monopoly\ Money\ Counter.app-Simulated.xcent -framework FBLPromises -framework GoogleUtilities -framework nanopb -framework GoogleAppMeasurement -framework GoogleAppMeasurementIdentitySupport -framework GoogleMobileAds -framework UserMessagingPlatform -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Serg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Monopoly_Money_Counter-dlchnwqjswrpalbdpoofeqhxekuc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Monopoly\ Money\ Counter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Monopoly\ Money\ Counter.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Monopoly\ Money\ Counter_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Serg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Monopoly_Money_Counter-dlchnwqjswrpalbdpoofeqhxekuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Monopoly\ Money\ Counter.app/Monopoly\ Money\ Counter
```

Comment: Try `pod deintegrate; pod update` and/or Build -> Clean in Xcode

Comment: Tried this. Didn't help. Maybe the problem is in x64 x86 architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to end of podfile fixed the error for me.

```
post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64 i386"
   end
   end
 end
```

Reference:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94914#issuecomment-992898782